# Why I am Getting Error "panic: missing emulator engine program for 'x86' cpu."

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I am Running Command ionic cordova run android its not working there was a error called "panic: missing emulator engine program for 'x86' cpu."

I am Working on Mac.Can I have A Solution

Answer (score 2):

you need to change CPU ABI x86 to x86_64 in order to run from Command line.
The emulator engine program is not supported x86.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

[see the ABI in the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTBXz.png)